# Exception message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework 4 )

Tags: c#, devexpress, iis-6, windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net-4.0

This error is shown after few seconds in ASP.NET Grid View (one specific page) where it shows a list of shops,The major problem is that this error does not occur on Local host if the dev team tries to debug the web application to find out this error where the data does not load properly so therefore its hard to find the root cause for this issue.The exception is thrown out when this application is accessed via internet after navigating to this specific page.I have managed to take logs from IIS to find out the method where this error exactly occurs.

```
Exception information:
    Exception type: TargetInvocationException
    Exception message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

### IIS Log (Event Viewer)

```
Event code: 3005
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
Event time: 22/07/2015 12:14:54
Event time (UTC): 22/07/2015 06:44:54
Event ID: 805078a2cfcc4523ad467862037dd16d
Event sequence: 5
Event occurrence: 2
Event detail code: 0

Application information:
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/JKHUAT-1-130820210921302025
    Trust level: Full
    Application Virtual Path: /JKHUAT
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\JKHUAT\
    Machine name: DMS-APPSRV2

Process information:
    Process ID: 4440
    Process name: w3wp.exe
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\JKHTest

Exception information:
    Exception type: TargetInvocationException
    Exception message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.InvokeMethod(ObjectDataSourceMethod method, Boolean disposeInstance, Object& instance)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments)
   at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.DataHelper.PerformSelect()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.HybridDataHelper.PerformSelect()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxDataWebControlBase.PerformSelect(String dataHelperName)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxDataWebControlBase.PerformSelect()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.ASPxTreeList.EnsureNodesCreated()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.Internal.TreeListDataHelper.CreateRows()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.Internal.TreeListDataHelper.EnsureRows()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.Internal.TreeListBuilderHelper.Build(ITreeListBuilder builder)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.Internal.TreeListDataTable.CreateControlHierarchy()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.InternalTable.CreateChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.InternalTable.DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.IASPxWebControl.EnsureChildControls()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.CreateChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControls()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.IASPxWebControl.EnsureChildControls()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.CreateChildControls()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.CreateChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.FindControl(String id)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Zamsana.Vantage.BusinessLogic.OutletCategory.GetTree_CAOC(UserCredential credential) in F:\TFS2013VS2010\JKH\Dev\Zamsana.Vantage.BusinessLogic\Category.cs:line 18



Request information:
    Request URL: http://discovery.keells.lk/JKHUAT/OutletView.aspx
    Request path: /JKHUAT/OutletView.aspx
    User host address: 192.168.254.31
    User: UserName
    Is authenticated: True
    Authentication Type: Forms
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\JKHTest

Thread information:
    Thread ID: 6
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\JKHTest
    Is impersonating: False
    Stack trace:    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.InvokeMethod(ObjectDataSourceMethod method, Boolean disposeInstance, Object& instance)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments)
   at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.DataHelper.PerformSelect()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.HybridDataHelper.PerformSelect()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxDataWebControlBase.PerformSelect(String dataHelperName)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxDataWebControlBase.PerformSelect()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.ASPxTreeList.EnsureNodesCreated()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.Internal.TreeListDataHelper.CreateRows()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.Internal.TreeListDataHelper.EnsureRows()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.Internal.TreeListBuilderHelper.Build(ITreeListBuilder builder)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.Internal.TreeListDataTable.CreateControlHierarchy()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.InternalTable.CreateChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.InternalTable.DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.IASPxWebControl.EnsureChildControls()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.CreateChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControls()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.IASPxWebControl.EnsureChildControls()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control, Boolean skipContentContainers)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(Control control)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.CreateChildControls()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.CreateChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.FindControl(String id)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Custom event details:
```

### Refer the Method that IIS Error Log shows

```
public static IQueryable GetTree_CAOC(UserCredential credential)
        {
            VantageDataContext db = new VantageDataContext();

            if (credential.DistributorUID.HasValue)
            {
                List<int> fullCatUIDList = new List<int>();
                List<int> catUIDList = new List<int>();
                List<int> dupCatUIDList = new List<int>();

                var categoryUID5s = (from di in db.DistributorOutlets
                                     join o in db.Outlets on di.OutletUID equals o.UID
                                     where di.DistributorUID == credential.DistributorUID.Value
                                          && o.OutletCategory5UID != null
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         CategoryUID = o.OutletCategory5UID
                                     }
                                     ).Distinct();

                foreach (var categoryUID5 in categoryUID5s)
                {
                    int uid = (int)categoryUID5.CategoryUID;

                    if (!catUIDList.Contains(uid))
                        catUIDList.Add(uid);

                    if (!fullCatUIDList.Contains(uid))
                        fullCatUIDList.Add(uid);
                }

                bool flag = true;
                while (flag)
                {
                    dupCatUIDList.Clear();
                    dupCatUIDList.AddRange(catUIDList);

                    var cats = from ca in db.OutletCategories
                               where dupCatUIDList.Contains(ca.UID)
                                && ca.ParentUID != null
                               select new { ca.ParentUID };

                    catUIDList.Clear();

                    foreach (var cat in cats)
                    {
                        int uid = (int)cat.ParentUID;

                        if (!catUIDList.Contains(uid))
                            catUIDList.Add(uid);

                        if (!fullCatUIDList.Contains(uid))
                            fullCatUIDList.Add(uid);
                    }

                    if (catUIDList.Count == 0)
                        flag = false;
                }

                var result = from oc in db.OutletCategories
                             orderby oc.Depth, oc.Description
                             where fullCatUIDList.Contains(oc.UID)
                                && oc.ExpiryDate == null
                             select new
                             {
                                 oc.UID,
                                 oc.Description,
                                 oc.ParentUID,
                                 oc.Depth
                             };

                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = from oc in db.OutletCategories
                             orderby oc.Depth, oc.Description
                             where oc.ExpiryDate == null
                             select new
                             {
                                 oc.UID,
                                 oc.Description,
                                 oc.ParentUID,
                                 oc.Depth
                             };

                return result;
            }
        }
```

*Development team debugged this code and there were no null values appearing in the above code blocks* Any idea why this exception is thrown out of the ASP.net web application?

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Comment: the only possible NullReferenceException i see when input parameter credential is null. Maybe this function is executed by anonymous user ?

Comment: @Disappointed I checked the code again when I debug the credential value is not null,and the value that is shown is also correct if I  Step over during debug it goes to if (credential.DistributorUID.HasValue) statement and on...to verify further is there is any possibility  you modify this method to show its credential.DistributorUID.Value as a alert or something when I load this page?

Comment: Yes, i know that during debug your credential  is not null(otherwise you would catch exception during debug). Maybe your credentials are taken from some time dependent storage(like cookie) and that's why it can occurs on production and cannot be reproduce during debug ?

Comment: On your place i would add some logging, for example the simplest file logging. For example System.IO.File.Append(YourCredential, YourFilePath) in the beggining of `GetTree_CAOC` method

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback @disappointed,I was able to confirm that credential value  becomes `NULL` and I got a another build hard-coding the above credential values then the grid loaded the data properly without giving any error,so I decided to modify the code as mentioned below and it worked for me !

```
 public static IQueryable GetTree_CAOC(UserCredential credential)
    {
        VantageDataContext db = new VantageDataContext();

        if (credential.DistributorUID.HasValue)
        {
            int DistributorUID = credential.DistributorUID.Value;
            List<int> fullCatUIDList = new List<int>();
            List<int> catUIDList = new List<int>();
            List<int> dupCatUIDList = new List<int>();

            var categoryUID5s = (from di in db.DistributorOutlets
                                 join o in db.Outlets on di.OutletUID equals o.UID
                                 where di.DistributorUID == DistributorUID
                                      && o.OutletCategory5UID != null
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     CategoryUID = o.OutletCategory5UID
                                 }
                                 ).Distinct();

            foreach (var categoryUID5 in categoryUID5s)
            {
                int uid = (int)categoryUID5.CategoryUID;

                if (!catUIDList.Contains(uid))
                    catUIDList.Add(uid);

                if (!fullCatUIDList.Contains(uid))
                    fullCatUIDList.Add(uid);
            }

            bool flag = true;
            while (flag)
            {
                dupCatUIDList.Clear();
                dupCatUIDList.AddRange(catUIDList);

                var cats = from ca in db.OutletCategories
                           where dupCatUIDList.Contains(ca.UID)
                            && ca.ParentUID != null
                           select new { ca.ParentUID };

                catUIDList.Clear();

                foreach (var cat in cats)
                {
                    int uid = (int)cat.ParentUID;

                    if (!catUIDList.Contains(uid))
                        catUIDList.Add(uid);

                    if (!fullCatUIDList.Contains(uid))
                        fullCatUIDList.Add(uid);
                }

                if (catUIDList.Count == 0)
                    flag = false;
            }

            var result = from oc in db.OutletCategories
                         orderby oc.Depth, oc.Description
                         where fullCatUIDList.Contains(oc.UID)
                            && oc.ExpiryDate == null
                         select new
                         {
                             oc.UID,
                             oc.Description,
                             oc.ParentUID,
                             oc.Depth
                         };

            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            var result = from oc in db.OutletCategories
                         orderby oc.Depth, oc.Description
                         where oc.ExpiryDate == null
                         select new
                         {
                             oc.UID,
                             oc.Description,
                             oc.ParentUID,
                             oc.Depth
                         };

            return result;
        }
    }
```